# Cannot call the animate function of the html graph onclick again and again

Tags: javascript

I have done a column graph which animates on windows load.Now I want to animate the graph on click as well as the animation will appear on windows load..the code in published in github

Comment: Please add your relevant code here.  Off-site links die over time.

Answer (score 0):

You should just stick to using jQuery if you have already added it to the page before any of your code will run.

Since `graphanimate` is a function you can reference it multiple times to run during both events

```
$(graphanimate) // fire on dom content loaded
$('.some-selector').on('click', graphanimate) // fire on click
```

Comment: no, you need to provide a minimal example of your code with your answer

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/97295a713329e17909a1fc8cc01ef600/c3e42288399a53d6228cc32dcad04fd03099f5b4